# Números Randômicos sem repetição.(JavaScript)

Tags: javascript, random

Bom dia,
Criei um pequeno jogo de loteria, onde é gerado 06 números entre 0-20, o usuário informa seu palpite de 06 números e o sistema retorna quantos números foram acertados e quais os números acertados.

O problema é que os números gerados aleatoriamente tem repetição, quero sugestões de como posso resolver esse problema para o código ser mais confiável?
Agradeço qualquer ajuda.

```
<script type="text/javascript">     
    jogo = [];
    sorteio = [];
    acertos = [];

    i = 1;

    while(i<=6){
        jogo.push(Math.round(Math.random()*20));
        sorteio.push(parseInt(prompt("Informe a "+i+"ª Dezena!")));
        i++;        
    };
    for (var i = 0; i<jogo.length; i++) {
        if(sorteio.indexOf(jogo[i])>-1){
            acertos.push(jogo[i]);
        }           
    };

    alert("Sorteio: "+jogo+"\nAposta: "+sorteio+"\nVocê acertou " + acertos.length + " números: "+ acertos);

    console.log(jogo);
    console.log(sorteio);
    console.log(acertos);
    console.log("Você acertou " + acertos.length + " números: ", acertos);

</script>
```

Comment: Guarde os números já sorteados em um hashmap. A cada novo número, se você sortear um que já saiu, sorteie de novo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pra não mudar muito a estrutura do seu código, basicamente você vai alterar a linha `jogo.push(Math.round(Math.random()*20));` pra usar essa estrutura:

```
while(i<=6){
    var novoNum = -1;
    do {
        novoNum = Math.round(Math.random()*20);
    } while (jogo.indexOf(novoNum) >= 0);
    jogo.push(novoNum);

    //segue o código
};
```

A ideia é que antes de adicionar o número sorteado ao array de números, checar se ele já está lá.

Comment: Muito obrigado @rLinhares , implementei as mudanças, após 10 tentativas não houve repetição....Valeu.